# SQL server ORDER BY - fast when column included in an index, super slow when not

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I know there are a lot of similar SO questions but none of them seem to quite answer my query.
Anyhow I'd tried to do a query of a SQL server table that was effectively

```
select top 5 * from MyTable WHERE [Timestamp]>'2021-11-09' ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

In order to get the 5 most recent entries (NB it has no identity column). Timestamp is a DATETIME field.
The table has 6 million+ records and this query was taking over 2 minutes so I gave up.
I then modified once of the existing indices (for an unrelated column), and added Timestamp as included column. This required rebuilding the index, but it took a few seconds at most, then after doing so, I re-ran the above query only to have it return almost instantly!  Thinking this was just some caching quirk, I took the Timestamp column out of the index and tried again - and sure even it went back to taking 2 minutes.  Re-adding the column to the index allowed it to complete within seconds.
Note that if I take out the WHERE clause above, the query still takes minutes (in fact, it's still running, has been for 6 minutes as I type) either way.
So what's going on here - if SQL server is able to rebuild the index in seconds then run the query in seconds, why can't it do that automatically under the hood when running the query without an index?
But more importantly, why would adding timestamp as an *included* column to an index on some other column make such difference to performance anyway?

Some other queries that run quite quickly either way:

```
select top 5 [Timestamp] from [MyTable] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC

select top 5 [Timestamp] from [MyTable] WHERE [Timestamp] > '2021-11-09'

select top 5 [PrimaryKey],[IndexedColumn],[Timestamp] FROM [MyTable] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC

select * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Timestamp] IN ('2021-11-09 05:00:45.030','2021-11-09 05:00:15.000','2021-11-09 05:00:45.850','2021-11-09 05:00:15.847','2021-11-09 04:59:45.830')
```

This last one puzzles me, because I got those 5 timestamps from the first query. But if I run:

```
select top 5 [Timestamp] INTO #LastTimestamps from [MyTable] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC;
select * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Timestamp] IN (SELECT [Timestamp] FROM #LastTimestamps)
```

the second query is super slow (3+ minutes).
Interestingly when comparing the execution plans for the query with the hard-coded timestamps and the one with the temp table, the former does an index scan of the index that includes the Timestamp column, whereas the latter does a clustered index scan of the primary key (which is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER). Why on earth such a difference when I'm querying exactly the same thing?

I then tried:

```
with LastKeys as (select top 5 [PrimaryKey] from [MyTable] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC)
select * FROM [MyTable] where [PrimaryKey] IN (SELECT [PrimaryKey] FROM LastKeys)
```

And that was able to return super quickly - in other words, SQL server is quite capable of finding the last 5 rows very quickly, even without temporary tables etc., but doesn't seem to be smart enough to come up with execution plan that does so automatically.

Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: Could you paste the plan of the query that uses index? And what is the size of table in MBs?

Comment: Any meaningful comment would have to be based on on the actual execution plan. SQL Server will be building the execution plan based on what it knows from statistics and the data cardinality, possibly there's a key-lookup being execution millions of times in the slow version. Add the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: Unfortunately the DB I was testing on has been taken offline for maintenance, and I'm not sure when I'll be able to access it again.  I did create a copy of the table in another DB but that's not displaying exactly the same behaviours. In that case the execution plan is just a regular Table Scan, but it's still quite fast (even without adding the timestamp column to the index).   It's 8336 Mb for the data file and 136 Mb for the index.

Comment: Turned out that copy didn't even have the primary key set, so I added it, and now it's doing a clustered index scan, but is very quick, despite the same amount of data and the same plan taking minutes on the original DB.  Not sure if that's a clue that the index needs rebuilding on the source database?

Comment: Update: just ran the query again with a tiny modification (changing the comparison date for the Timestamp > X test), and now it's doing quite a different plan, which does look more like the one I saw on the original database, where it's doing a non-clustered index scan.  But either way it's very fast (a couple of seconds). https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1jrrfFPF

Comment: I can sort of understand that it decides it's more efficient to scan the non-clustered index to find matching values for [Timestamp] than it is scanning the whole table, but it's just how long it takes when doing the latter that I don't get, esp. when I can't reproduce that with the copied DB.

Comment: Ok I was able to find another DB instance that was displaying the same problems, in fact a good deal worse, it's a slightly different query, but it took over 8 minutes to find a single row out of 6 million:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkdqpMKPF

Comment: Comparing that the actual execution plan from the copied DB I can't see at all why it takes over 8 minutes for one and a few seconds for the other - but one curious difference is the number of physical reads (132 vs 0).